# How can I wire this RF receiver up to control a low-voltage motor?

Tags: rf, schematics

The instructions are sparse (for me) but I figured you guys would know how to hook this thing up in a jiffy. It requires a 12V power source.

[image: From the manual]

and here is a picture of the terminals

[image]

Comment: The "NC" "COM" and "NO" terminals are the contacts of the relay, NC means "Normally Closed" and is *normally connected to the COM terminal* until the relay is turned on. The NO is the opposite and is "Normally Open" until the relay it turned on.

Comment: and you can just see under the terminals the 2nd from the right is marked IN-  and the rightmost connector is marked IN+ (power IN). On the package there is a wire connection between IN- and COM with the load between IN+ and NO. i.e the relay switches the load to ground when it closes.

Comment: Wow, a relay with anode and cathode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the diagram is self-explanatory but however you should do the following:

connect

1. the + of your power supply to IN+
2. the - of your power supply to IN-
3. IN- to COM
4. one motor terminal to IN+
5. the other motor terminal to COM

the diagram says that the supply could be 6v, 12v or 24v so choose the one which is the same of your motor's voltage.